# Playing a 3 note chord on GarageBand performs an UNDO function

Tags: ipad, garageband, ios, ipados

I have a 1st edition iPad Pro 12.9" and I opened GarageBand. It loaded an old song automatically, and the instrument was a synth. I switched it to a Grand Piano and began to play a 3 note chord. As I played the chord a couple of times, the instrument switch back to the synth.

I tried a few more times and the same thing happened. I finally tracked it down to it performing an undo function, and I was able to select redo to change the instrument back to a Grand Piano. Every time I play a 3 note chord, it does this undo making it very hard to play what I am trying to play. It happens for any chord I play and on both sides of the screen.

I am running the beta of iPadOS as well, if that matters!

Is this normal? I've not really used GarageBand on my iPad much...

Answer (score 3):

In iPadOS 13 undo and redo are three finger gestures. Undo is supposed to be a three finger *swipe* to the left and redo a three finger swipe to the right. The movement to or from a three finger chord certainly may be recognized as a quick swipe. Try disabling gestures in Settings. Because this is in beta the location of settings like this may change between releases. I'd look in Settings->General and disable gestures to start.

Comment: That's amazing. That's the worst coincidence of overlapping gestures I could imagine for such an app!

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact the undo behavior which cannot yet be disabled in iPadOS.  However this is unique to GarageBand as other sequencers like (Cubasis) don’t have the same issue